# Getting 404 response from flask, stumped

Tags: python, flask, http-status-code-404, arcgis

Have a simple flask app as follows:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import jsonify

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello(): 
    return "<h3>Hello World!</h3>Your app is working.<br/></br/>{}".format(hex(random.randint(0,1000000)))

@app.route('/echo', methods=['POST'])
def hello1():
   return jsonify(request.json(force=True))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=8002, use_reloader=True)
```

A direct query confirms connectivity:

```
http://172.31.26.169:8002/ yields:

Hello World!
Your app is working.
```

requests.get work fine.

But the following results in the server responding with a 404.

```
response = requests.post("http://172.31.26.169:8002/echo", json={"mytext":"lalala"})
```

My IDE is Wing Pro, the overall install is in an ArcGIS conda clone environment.

I've been at this for over a day and am stumped. Any suggestions are most welcome!!

Comment: Are you sure you're running this exact code?  The first response from the `"/"` route should have included a random hex number at the end, but it did not.

Comment: Yes, I didn't include it in the cut/paste for brevity/clarity.

Comment: Hopefully you can see now that you actually achieved the _opposite_ of clarity, because you made it appear that you were running different code.

Comment: My only guess is that it's a side issue, not anything wrong with the code itself.  i.e. maybe you forgot to **save** the code before running it, or maybe you should have used `https:` instead of `http:`, or you used the wrong ip address,  or the wrong port, etc etc.

Comment: Solved. The ArcGIS clone environment only allows adding packages using it's package manager. I found a flask-json package that was not included in the default flaskk package, now it doesn't reject the post.

Answer (score 0):

Try request.get_json() without setting force.

Comment: Didn't solve the original issue, but once that was solve this comment solved the next one.  Thx!!